# type mismatch in re-declaration error in doubly linked list using project file in c

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, project, doubly-linked-list

I converted my code to a project file as per requirement.

after converting it I got some redeclaration errors:

**type mismatch in redeclaration of** `'n'`

**declaration syntax error** for `n* create_node(int);`

**UPDATED CODE**

new error upon running:

new, first and last are undefined in some of my included files.

CIRC.H file:

```
#ifndef CIRC_H
#define CIRC_H

struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;    
};

typedef struct node n;

struct node * create_node(int);
int add_node();
int insert_at_first();
int insert_at_end();
int insert_at_position();
int delete_node_position();
int sort_list();
int update();
int search();
int display_from_beg();
int display_in_rev();



#endif
```

CIRC.C File:

```
    #include "CIRC.H"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node *new, *ptr, *prev; 
struct node *first = NULL, *last = NULL;
int number = 0;


void main(){

    int ch;
    clrscr();

    while (1){
       //textt
    }
}

struct node * create_node(int info){
    number++;
     new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(n));
    new->val = info;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `n` isn't a type; its a var. try `struct node * create_node(int info);`, etc. this problem is replicated *throughout* your code. I see no sense for `n` *at all* in this code.

Comment: @WhozCraig tried, now i get an expression syntax error in new = (n *)malloc(sizeof(n));

Comment: Read that comment again. There is no reason for `n` in *any* of this code. You don't alias a type by declaring an `extern` variable; you do it by declaring a `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess instead of this :

```
struct n *new,
```

You meant

```
struct node *new,
```

And here instead of

```
n* create_node(int);
```

=>
    struct node * create_node(int);

Comment: tried now i get an expression syntax error in new = (n *)malloc(sizeof(n));

Comment: @hushpuppies Same, instead of (n*) write (struct node*)

Comment: @hushpuppies i think it is another question, debuger is your friend now ))